# Android AsyncTask doInBackground behavior has changed in Android7

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My app has a Fragment with an AsyncTask that fetches records from a database and displays them using a ListView. Has been running fine for a couple of years, but now on Android 7 it stalls, with no records displayed. However, upon leaving the app (eg going into Android settings) then returning, records are then displayed. 
Debugging shows that onPreExecute is executed initially, but doInBackground is not executed until the moment of leaving the app.

Can anyone suggest what has changed in Android 7 that might explain this?

```
        // 1. ==== Fragment containing AsyncTask ====

        public class AuditFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener
        {

            // Using beep for debugging until I can get LogCat in Eclipse restored for Android 7 
            public static void beep ( final int times )
            {
                ...
            }

            private class UpdateAuditTask extends AsyncTask<Void, RecordEntry, SQLException>
            {

                @Override
                protected SQLException doInBackground ( Void... parameters )
                {
                    beep ( 5 ); // Debug, in the absence of LogCat
                    ...   
                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate ( RecordEntry... values )
                {
                    L.logMethodCall ( (Object[]) values );

                    if ( values.length == 1 )
                        {
                        auditListAdapter.add ( values[0] );
                        auditListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                        }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute ()
                {
                    L.logMethodCall ();
                    beep ( 2 ); // Debug, in the absence of LogCat
                    auditListAdapter.clear ();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute ( SQLException result )
                {
                    L.logMethodCall ( result );
                    ...
                }
            }

            private void updateAuditList ()
            {
                L.logMethodCall ();

                beep (1);  // Debug, in the absence of LogCat

                new UpdateAuditTask ().execute ();
                auditListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
            }

            public AuditFragment()
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick ( View view )
            {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState )
            {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart ()
            {
                L.logMethodCall ();
                super.onStart ();

                getListView ().setAdapter ( auditListAdapter );
                updateFragmentGui ();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume ()
            {
                L.logMethodCall ();
                super.onResume ();
                ...
            }

            private void updateFragmentGui ()
            {
                L.logMethodCall ();
                ...
            }

            private class AuditListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RecordEntry>
            {
                ...
            }

        }

        // 2. ==== Activity which executes Fragment ====

        public class AuditActivity extends Activity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                L.logMethodCall(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.audit);

                // Add "static" fragments
                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    AuditFragment audit = new AuditFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.kstation_audit_audit_frag, audit);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void finish() {
                super.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.donothing, R.anim.collapse_righttoleft);
            }
        }

        // 3. ==== Method in main Activity ====

        public void showAudit() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(C.getActivity(), AuditActivity.class);
                C.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
```

I am testing on a Samsung SM-T580.
When app is "stalled" after onPreExecute has run, any of the following actions causes doInBackground to execute immediately:                                  - touch the Recent button
- press the Home key
- scroll down and select the Settings icon

It would seem that a change in the lifecycle state of AuditFragment or its parent Activity is unblocking the execution of doInBackground.

Update: I have managed to restore LogCat visibility for Android 7 (used sdk tools Monitor rather than Eclipse) and so get some debug information.

Experiments : 
    - restore updateAuditTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)  (rather than use my own executor)
    and output THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR properties to LogCat just before calling executeOnExecutor

1. Android 7. Stalls, ie doInBackground does not execute.

   ```
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getCorePoolSize ()  : 4
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getMaximumPoolSize(): 17
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getPoolSize()       : 4
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getActiveCount()    : 4
   ```
2. Android 6. Does not stall, ie doInBackground does  execute.

   ```
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getCorePoolSize ()  : 5
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getMaximumPoolSize(): 9
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getPoolSize()       : 5
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getActiveCount()    : 5
   ```

I am puzzled by this: in each case there are not less than core pool size threads currently active;
the new task runs in Android6 but not in Android7.

Experiment 2.
Disable one AsyncTask that starts earlier. This time, THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR properties remain same as before, but task does not stall.

3. Android 7. Does not stall, ie doInBackground does execute.

   ```
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getCorePoolSize ()  : 4
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getMaximumPoolSize(): 17
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getPoolSize()       : 4
           THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.getActiveCount()    : 4
   ```

So it would appear that pool sizes etc are not having a bearing on whether the task executes?

(Clarification. Earlier, I mistakenly reported that I had tried it with earlier tasks disabled; I had instead disabled some tasks that run on separate threads.)

Comment: Post your code.  I have a hunch the problem is in your `Activity`, not the `AsyncTask` itself.

Comment: Are you running any other async tasks?

Comment: Yes, there are several other AsyncTasks running. However, yesterday I tried the following change without success:

    // 27/06/17 This should be a general improvement
     //new UpdateAuditTask ().execute ();

     UpdateAuditTask updateAuditTask = new UpdateAuditTask ();

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
         updateAuditTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);
     else
         updateAuditTask.execute((Void[])null);

Comment: Calling `executeOnExecutor` with `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXEC‌​UTOR` just runs it on the same executor it would have run on anyway.  Try running it on another executor that you provide.

Comment: Your suggestion has worked. I created a ThreadPoolExecutor from details in   https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html.  Now to tidy it up a bit. Thank you.

Comment: Until I can determine the circumstances that cause AsyncTasks to fail in Android 7, I will be concerned that other AsyncTasks in the app that are performing background work, eg sync of records with server, may also fail.

Comment: There could be long-running AsyncTasks inside third party libraries that you have no control over. I'd say avoid using AsyncTask entirely until this is resolved.  (Or forever, since Google [keeps screwing this up](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/).)

Comment: I have added LogCat output from some experiments.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: I have added report of experiment to disable a long running  AsyncTask that is started earlier.

Comment: If this [AsyncTask source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) is up to date, I was mistaken about which executor `execute()` uses by default.  Apparently it's `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR`. But that doesn't explain why it doesn't run when you execute on `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `AsyncTask.execute()` uses `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR`, so a single long-running task will prevent any other task from running.  I discovered this by looking at the [Marshmallow `AsyncTask` source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) and verified it on my 6.0.1 device.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... voids) {
        Log.d("DERP", "bad task starting");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            // ignore
        }
        finally {
            Log.d("DERP", "bad task exiting");
        }
        return null;
    }
}.execute();

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... voids) {
        Log.d("DERP", "nice task running");
        return null;
    };
}.execute();
```

Output:

```
06-30 15:43:23.777 8761-8792/com.chalcodes.rogueasynctask D/DERP: bad task starting
06-30 15:43:28.777 8761-8792/com.chalcodes.rogueasynctask D/DERP: bad task exiting
06-30 15:43:28.779 8761-9084/com.chalcodes.rogueasynctask D/DERP: nice task running
```

I'd suggest using `executeOnExecutor(...)` and supplying your own executor.  If two tasks that you don't control are interfering with each other, you could use this hack to change the default executor.  `AsyncTask` has a public static `setDefaultExecutor` method, but it's marked `@hide` so you have to access it via reflection.

```
try {
    final Method method = AsyncTask.class.getMethod("setDefaultExecutor", Executor.class);
    method.invoke(null, executor);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("AsyncTask", "error setting default executor", e);
}
```

But this doesn't explain what changed between Android 6 and 7.  Maybe something unrelated to `AsyncTask` changed that is causing one `AsyncTask` to block the serial executor.

These are the commits that changed `AsyncTask` in Android 7.  I don't see a smoking gun.

- [Tweak AsyncTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR settings](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/2b0ebb3d5d101895ebdcd394c53025391c360763)
- [More maybe fix issue #22765972: Binder transactions running out of address space causing package manager to fail](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/6b42bc0e2191805ac1dfdb1cbf2782b29dd7c585)
- [Fix AsyncTask to handle exceptions in doInBackground](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/78a8e9d2939dcb7be3d3a656c6ac630f17d73854)
- [AsyncTask terminating with exception calls onCancelled](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/5eb91a437c551ed0c66b38299f988f8159ada207)

Comment: Thanks. I will try a version that disables the other AsyncTasks to see if that makes a dfference.

Comment: Disabling the other AsyncTasks makes no difference. My "beep" debugging confirms that onPreExecute is executed, but doInBackground is not.

But the documentation for AsyncTask says:
doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing.

Comment: // We want at least 2 threads and at most 4 threads in the core pool.     The above change in Android7 to limit the number of threads to 4  may be contributing to the problem; but I cannot account for the behavior in terms of the values my debugs reported for THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR: no consistency between Android 6 and 7.  I am now supplying my own executor as Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor () rather than the more elaborate one I first tried, and this seems fine. Might there be any downside from supplying your own executor?

Comment: @user5997813 I don't think it uses `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, so that change shouldn't make a difference.  It seems strange that it would work with a single thread executor but not with the default `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`, which is effectively the same thing.

Comment: I just confirmed that with Android7 it does not work using either task.execute()  or task.execute (AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) but only using task.execute (Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())      I already tested that the first two work with Android 6.

Comment: @user5997813 That's very strange.  I haven't found anything else or come up with any more ideas.  It seems like what you are observing could only be caused by misbehaving `AsyncTask`s (possibly within third party libraries) hogging all the threads in both `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` and `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`.  The different behavior on Android 7 could be totally unrelated to `AsyncTask` itself, and instead be some change related to what some particular `AsyncTask` is trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue on the app I'm working on it. It's really weird because the same code is working on some other devices, with the same version, configuration...
However, a workaround could help you : use **Rx** instead of AsyncTask. I can't explain the main reason but it fixes my blocking issue.